# Accessing object inside the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a json -

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Mr",
    "student": {
      "name": "John"
    }
  }
]
```

I have my `fetch` API as -

```
let response = await fetch('https://api....', reqOptions);

if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    const body = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        studentList: body
    });
    } else {
        let error = response;
        throw error;
    }
```

I map it -

```
return this.state.studentList.map((student) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{student.name}</Text>
        </View>
    )
})
```

But `student.name` is undefined. I can only access `student.id` or `student.title`. How can I access the name which is inside student object?

Comment: `student.student.name`

Comment: doesnt seem to wrk

Comment: Either your initial example for the data is wrong or you misspelled something. Is there an error when using `student.student.name`?

Comment: sorry had a typo error...works now!!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are trying to access a property that is not in the parent. The name property belongs to the student property.

You can try destructuring the student object from the parent. 
IE...

```
return this.state.studentList.map(({ student }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{student.name}</Text>
        </View>
    )
})
```